# How can I do alphanumeric with space regex model validation in CakePHP?

Tags: php, regex, validation, cakephp

I have a user registration form and I only want the user to specify their first and last name (i.e. Donalg Doonsberry). If the user doesn't provide their name in this fashion, the input will be rejected. I thought something like this would work for my regex user validation in cakephp:

```
  'name'=>array('Name has to be comprised of letters.
                '=>array('rule'=>array('custom', '/[A-Za-z ]+/')
           )),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to be careful validating names... what about:

- Donalg McDonald <- capital in the middle of a word
- Donalg Fooble-Whiffery <- hyphenated
- Donalg Déénsbnérry-McDonald Sr. 3rd <- you get the idea

To validate names in the format you specified:

```
/[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+/
```

Being a bit more lenient:

```
/([\w.-]+ )+[\w+.-]/
```

Comment: +1 I second the notion that trying to validate human names with regex is nonsense. I'm not even sure what that would be good for.

Comment: how do you validate that the user inputs data that is not malicious?

Comment: You shouldn't need to - you should escape it properly every time you use it - either in an SQL query (e.g. mysql_real_escape_string) or outputting to a page (e.g. htmlspecialchars)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't bother with first/last name validation. You can only validate their length (there is a built-in validation rule in cake for that) and make sure you put "allowEmpty" => true, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below to validate fields with alphaNumeric and with spaces.

```
'rule1' = array(
   'rule' => array('custom','/([\w.-]+ )+[\w+.-]/'),
   'required' => true,
   'message' => 'Required field.'
)
```

I hope help you.